# Algorithm - find the longest string

Tags: algorithm

On exam I had to write the algorithm that would give the answer to that question:

"In **numbers.txt** file there are 500 numbers separated by new lines. Find the longest string of numbers whose largest common divisor is greater than one. In other words, there exists a number that is a divisor of them all.
As an answer give a value of the first number in the string, the length of the string and the number which is GCD of them all."

My first idea was soo not optimal. I didn't write it but conception is something that looks like that:

```
int numbers[500]; // array for numbers

ofstream allstrings;
allstrings.open("allstrings.txt");

int max; // lets say that i know what is max number

for(int i=2; i<x; i++)
{
    string found_string ="";
    for(int j=0; j<500; j++)
    {

        // looking for all strings whose common divisor is i
        if(foundstring)
        {
        allstrings << found_string << endl;
        found_string = "";
        }
    }

}
```

After that i would just find the longest string.

To be honest at the moment I don't have any better idea. I would be gratefull for any help :)

Comment: What is longest string of numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 500 numbers you can simply brute force this with O(n^2) gcd computations.

For each starting point try increasing the length of the string until the gcd becomes equal to 1.

Note that gcd(a,b,c) is equal to gcd(gcd(a,b),c) so you only need 1 extra gcd computation for each iteration of the loop.

### Example Python Code

```
A=[3,7,21,6,9,10]

from fractions import gcd
best = ''
for start,g in enumerate(A):
    length = 1
    for x in A[start:]:
        g = gcd(g,x)
        if g==1:
            break
        if length>len(best):
            best = A[start:start+length]
        length += 1
print best
```

this prints:

```
[21, 6, 9]
```

Comment: Could you write some code for example? I don't see it so clear yet.

Comment: Say the array is [6,7,12],  can this algorithm find the answer [6,12] with gcd = 6?

Comment: No it can't cause 7 separates them, there is not any string longer than 1 element.

Comment: @Smorts I've added some Python code to illustrate the answer

Answer (score 0):

If complexity matters, you can try factorizing your numbers first. Then for each prime number divisor of the previous number, try to 'prolong' the sequence. If numbers share some common divisor, the share a common divisor being a prime number, in particular. Moreover, the number of different prime divisors is quite small :

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409675/number-of-distinct-prime-factors-omegan

In other words, algorithm is dynamic. Keep the list of values (prime divisor, max_length). If the next number is divisible by p, then increase max_length of p, otherwise set it to 1. Easy factorization is at square root time or maybe you can use Euclidean sieve first.